# how return value to display message in codeignaitor

Tags: codeigniter

i have controller that delete row from database like :-

```
public function deletePost() {
    $events = new event_model();
    $ev_id=intval($_POST['ev_id']);

    $result = $events->deletePostWall($ev_id);      

}
```

and the model is  :-

```
function deletePostWall($ev_id) {
    $vales = array('ev_id' => $ev_id);
    $vales_comment = array('co_postid' => $ev_id);
    $query_done = $this->db->delete($this->table_name, $vales) or die (mysql_error());
    $query_done_comment = $this->db->delete('comment', $vales_comment) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

now this method is work good, but i need when delete success, send message in view to user that the delete is done.

how can do that.

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
public function deletePost() {
    $events = new event_model();
    $ev_id=intval($_POST['ev_id']);

    $result = $events->deletePostWall($ev_id);   

   if($result) {
        $this->data['success'] = "Deleted!";
        $this->load->view('VIEW-NAME',$this->data);    
    }   

}
```

Method:

```
function deletePostWall($ev_id) {
    $vales = array('ev_id' => $ev_id);
    $vales_comment = array('co_postid' => $ev_id);
    $query_done = $this->db->delete($this->table_name, $vales) or die (mysql_error());
    $query_done_comment = $this->db->delete('comment', $vales_comment) or die(mysql_error());
   return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php if (isset($success)) {echo $success;}?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its no delete and no message display

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

in controller

```
public function deletePost() {
    $events = new event_model();
    $ev_id=intval($_POST['ev_id']);

    $result = $events->deletePostWall($ev_id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Delete is done');
    redirect('controller_name/function_name','refresh');//redirect a function which loads your view.      

}
```

in view

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');}?>
```

Comment: i will try your code but its show me error :- <p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\AppServ

Comment: try this : in controller in the second line write ob_start();

Answer (score 0):

model

```
function deletePostWall($ev_id) {
    $vales = array('ev_id' => $ev_id);
    $vales_comment = array('co_postid' => $ev_id);
    $query_done = $this->db->delete($this->table_name, $vales) or die (mysql_error());
    $query_done_comment = $this->db->delete('comment', $vales_comment) or die(mysql_error());
   return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

controller

```
public function deletePost() {

    $events = new event_model();  
    $this->data['message'] = '';

    if($this->input->post()) {

        $ev_id=intval($this->input->post('ev_id'));

        $result = $events->deletePostWall($ev_id);   

        if($result) {
            $this->data['message'] = "Deleted!";

        }
        else {
           $this->data['message'] = "Not Deleted!";
        } 
    }        

    $this->load->view('VIEW-NAME',$this->data);
}
```

view

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```